# Pull start fuel injected motorcycle/car injured or not?

Tags: engine, electronic-control-module, fuel-injection, timing

A lot of time I heard from some people that pull start fuel injected motorcycle or car injured engine by shifting the time of engine or confuse EMS(Engine Management System computer) because tires turns in engine stop status. I completely reject all the time these idea if don't do this procedure a lot. I think EMS very dynamic and time system of engine is powerful enough that for example 100 pull start don't shift time. What is your opinion?
EMS -> ECU of engine

Comment: I’ve seen this break the crankshaft - guarantee it won’t start then...

Comment: What is the vehicle? Crankshaft completely broken?

Comment: "Break the crankshaft" yes.